# Where should programming techniques be discussed?

Tags: discussion

The question [Common interface pattern for writing struct members to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998805/common-interface-pattern-for-writing-struct-members-to-memory) was put on hold because "the answers would mainly consist of experience-based reports without facts".

So is SO not intended to solve this type of problem? The original question isn't particularly broad or diffuse, its just that you can't give a formal answer because most programming problems of sufficiently narrow range were not (and maybe never will be) handled in an academic way due to lack of audience.

Where to go with such requests? Newsgroups?

Comment: Programmers.SE (hopefully soon to be Software Engineering.SE) is probably the best location for this question.

Comment: see [What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)